# What is the "maximum" temperature for my GPU

Tags: gpu

I have http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/desktop/7000/7700. I want to overclock, but I don't know what the maximum temperature is.

Answer (score 1):

About 85C is what I would consider the sweet spot for a typical GPU. That is about the point where it is getting to the hot side but it is still not dangerously hot. Most recent GPUs (Including the AMD 7000 series GPUs) are designed to be able to handle up to about 100C without a problem but it is not a good idea to run them that hot for a long period of time and it can cause things like artifacts. I run my 7970's at about 85-90 degrees myself.